# Iteration: Approximation and Errors, finding all possible iterative arrangements

Tags: roots, approximation

I am looking at a relatively simple problem to reiterate:

$x^4=e^x$

I've found 5 different possible forms

1: $x_{r+1}=\frac{e^x}{x^3}$

2: $x_{r+1}=(\frac{e^x}{x^2})^{0.5}$

3: $x_{r+1}=(\frac{e^x}{x})^{1/3}$

4: $x_{r+1}=e^{x/4}$

5: $x_{r+1}=4Ln(x)$

The two roots are: $x_1=-0.815553, x_2=1.429612$

There are two possible roots that I've found graphically, and equations 2 and 4 both converge to $x_2$ but not $x_1$, and the other three doesn't converge to any. I've done my analytics and used $-1<F'(x)<1$ to verify which of them will actually converge. The question I have is how do I find an iterative process for $x_1$, and is it even possible?

I'm actually facing the same problem with other iterations I'm doing. So any help here will be useful.

Comment: Note that in $2$ and $4$, you're forcing $x_{r}$ to be positive no matter where you start. This is essentially incomplete because, for example $x^4=e^x \iff x = \pm e^{x/4}$, and you're only taking the solutions with the positive sign.The obvious way to sniff out the negative roots would be to also run the iteration with the negative signs ($x_{r+1} = - \exp{x_r/4}$ etc).

Comment: As to whether the rest would converge at all, the existence of a limit is contingent on fixed points existing and the repeated use of the map contracting to one. A sufficient condition for convergence is via the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). You might thus want to see if you can show that these are contractions, which is the simplest way to confirm this a priori.

Comment: Thanks...I completely missed that out. I do have another question, I'm trying to find all the interative arrangements for $x^3+100cos(x)=0$, again I'm facing the same problem. Tried the idea of negative roots but it didn't work out, and I've only managed to work out 2 of the 3 roots using $x=(+/-)arccos(-\frac{x^3}{100})$

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer, @user51515?

Comment: Just had a chance today, yes I see what you mean now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating $(e^x-x)/(x^3-1)$. I think if you start close enough to the negative solution, the iteration will converge to it.

For example, taking the starting point $x=-1$, we produce the sequence, -1, -.6839, -.9005, -.7553, -.8562, -.7870, -.8351, -.8019, -.8250, -.8090, -.8201, -.8124, $\dots$ seems to converge slowly but surely.